# Finding subdirectories that doesn not contain a file with name X

Tags: bash, testing, find

I have been struggling with finding subdirectories without a file called `UID_points.txt` where UID is dependent on the user. I have tried many variations according to other threads without success. The general idea is to use find and call test to test for the presence of the file, but It does not seem to use with a regex - what is wrong?

`find "topfolder/subfolder/" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not -exec test -f  {}/*points.txt \; -print`

Comment: (1) Why are you using `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` ? (2) `{}/*points.txt` does not expand `*` - that would be done by the shell. eg. `find "topfolder/subfolder/" -type d -exec bash -c 'for f in {}/*points.txt; do [ -f "$f" ] && exit 1; done; true' \; -print`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the suggestion of a shell from @jhnc and the knowledge of when things expand from @Socowi I derived this solution which in my humble opinion seems good

```
find "topfolder/subfolder/" \
  -mindepth 1 \
  -maxdepth 1 \
  -type d \
  -exec sh -c '[[ $(ls -A "{}"/*points.txt 2>/dev/null) ]] && exit 1; true' \; \
  -print
```

So instead if risking iterating again, which `find` already does I can simply check if a file is present and return a boolean accordingly.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the `*` is only expanded by shells. You don't run a shell but just the plain `test` command.

To fix this you can explicitly start a shell

```
find topfolder/subfolder/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
     -not -exec sh 'test -f  "$0"/*points.txt' {} \; -print
```

But note that this will probably fail if `*points.txt` matches more than one file. You can work around this by using `bash`'s `compgen`.

```
find topfolder/subfolder/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
     -not -exec bash 'compgen -G "$0/*points.txt" > /dev/null' {} \; -print
```

But then again you could run the search in plain `bash` altogether. This is probably faster than starting a new process for each directory.

```
for d in topfolder/subfolder/*/; do
  if ! compgen -G "$d/*points.txt" > /dev/null; then
    echo "$d"
   fi
done
```